# kinect v2 grey screen in kinect studio. Likely USB controller issue? Are there any work arounds for this issue?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-v2

So I've got a few Kinect v2s and am hoping to set up an array of them to get a 3D recording of an area in space (Eventual goal is to build a 360 image from multiple point clouds) But at the moment I can't even get one working on a machine.

I've installed the official SDK onto a windows 10 device and when opening the kinect studio I get nothing but a grey screen when connected to the kinect. Running the kinect configuration verfier says the USB controller is unknown and the system is waiting for the kinect to respond. The kinect itself does not light up, and it's cooling fan does not turn on.

I have reinstalled the SDK, tried 3 different kinects, tried various drivers and troubleshooting guides, and still cannot get anything out of the kinect.

The best answer I've found is that only some controllers are compatible, but every PC I have tried (currently 5 machines) have "Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)" So basically do I really have to get a PCI USB controller or another machine, or is there any way to get the current system to work with the kinect v2 at all.

Also if I do need to buy a new device or PCI card are there any recommended for a setup that would idealy run 4-5 kinects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Kinect V2 prevents you from simultaneously running more than one Kinect on a system:

> Sensor Acquisition and Startup
>   Kinect for Windows supports one sensor, which is called the default sensor. The KinectSensor Class has static members to help configure the Kinect sensor and access sensor data.

[Kinect API Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/kinect/dn782033(v=ieb.10))

A workaround that I've used in the past is to have 1 computer for every Kinect (doesn't have to be fancy, just enough to run it) and then network all the machines together with a router. Designate one machine to be the controlling machine (handles turning on/off of other Kinects). Depending on what you plan on doing to the data, it may be helpful to have those other machines perform some pre-processing and leave the stitching off all the Kinects' feeds up to the controlling machine.

As far as the USB controller goes, I'm running Kinect v2 on that exact one, so other than that malfunctioning, I think you're fine. Have you tried running the "Kinect v2 Configuration Verifier" to see what it suggests? [Kinect v2 Configuration Verifier](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/kinect)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'd run the config versifier and it said to check if the USB controller was valid if I recall. In the end I bought some PCIe USB 3.0 controllers and ran the kinect V2s via those.

It's also worth noting that you can in fact run multiple on the same machine if you use the open source libraries(one kinect V2 per USB 3.0 controller), however then the frame-rate from each device drops if you use too many due to limited bandwidth on the device used to run them.